# Handwritten digits recognition with keras

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, keras, mnist

I am trying to learn [Keras](https://keras.io/). I see machine learning code for recognizing handwritten digits [here](http://neuralnetworksanddeeplearning.com/chap1.html) (also given [here](https://github.com/mnielsen/neural-networks-and-deep-learning/blob/master/src/network.py)). It seems to have feedforward, SGD and backpropagation methods written from a scratch. I just want to know if it is possible to write this program using Keras? A starting step in that direction will be appreciated.

Comment: See [here](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/master/examples/mnist_mlp.py) for an MLP model and [here](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/master/examples/mnist_cnn.py) for a CNN one...

Comment: Can these be used for other, color image datasets also?

Comment: Your keyword search for this is CIFAR instead of MNIST

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this to understand how the MNIST dataset works for MLP first.[Keras MNIST tutorial](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/). As you proceed, you can look into how CNN works on the MNIST dataset.

I will describe a bit of the process of the keras code that you have attached to your comment

```
# Step 1: Organize Data
batch_size = 128   # This is split the 60k images into batches of 128, normally people use 100. It's up to you
num_classes = 10   # Your final layer. Basically number 0 - 9 (10 classes)
epochs = 20        # 20 'runs'. You can increase or decrease to see the change in accuracy. Normally MNIST accuracy peaks at around 10-20 epochs.

# the data, split between train and test sets
(x_train, y_train), (x_test, y_test) = mnist.load_data()  #X_train - Your training images, y_train - training labels; x_test - test images, y_test - test labels. Normally people train on 50k train images, 10k test images.

x_train = x_train.reshape(60000, 784) # Each MNIST image is 28x28 pixels. So you are flattening into a 28x28 = 784 array. 60k train images
x_test = x_test.reshape(10000, 784)   # Likewise, 10k test images
x_train = x_train.astype('float32')   # For float numbers
x_test = x_test.astype('float32')
x_train /= 255                        # For normalization. Each image has a 'degree' of darkness within the range of 0-255, so you want to reduce that range to 0 - 1 for your Neural Network
x_test /= 255
print(x_train.shape[0], 'train samples')
print(x_test.shape[0], 'test samples')

# convert class vectors to binary class matrices
y_train = keras.utils.to_categorical(y_train, num_classes)  # One-hot encoding. So when your NN is trained, your prediction for 5(example) will look like this [0000010000] (Final layer).
y_test = keras.utils.to_categorical(y_test, num_classes)


# Step 2: Create MLP model
model = Sequential()     
model.add(Dense(512, activation='relu', input_shape=(784,)))    #First hidden layer, 512 neurons, activation relu, input 784 array
model.add(Dropout(0.2))                                         # During the training, layer has 20% probability of 'switching off' certain neurons
model.add(Dense(512, activation='relu'))                        # Same as above
model.add(Dropout(0.2))
model.add(Dense(num_classes, activation='softmax'))   # Final layer, 10 neurons, softmax is a probability function to give the best probability of the input image

model.summary()


# Step 3: Create model compilation
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy',
              optimizer=RMSprop(),
              metrics=['accuracy'])
# 10 classes - categorical_crossentropy. If 2 classes, you can use binary_crossentropy; optimizer - RMSprop, you can change this to ADAM, SGD, etc...; metrics - accuracy


# Step 4: Train model
history = model.fit(x_train, y_train,
                    batch_size=batch_size,
                    epochs=epochs,
                    verbose=1,
                    validation_data=(x_test, y_test))
# Training happens here. Train on each batch size for 20 runs, the validate your result on the test set.

# Step 5: See results on your test data
score = model.evaluate(x_test, y_test, verbose=0)
# Prints out scores
print('Test loss:', score[0])
print('Test accuracy:', score[1])
```

Comment: Very well illustrated. I want to ask 2 points: First link in my question uses `net = network.Network([784, 30, 10])` or `net = network.Network([784, 100, 10])` while you seem to use `784,512,10` neurons in 3 main layers. How do you choose number of neurons? Also, in your tensorflow tutorial link, `flatten()` is used which you have not used at all.  What is it and is it important to be used?

Comment: Also, `SGD` seems to be used in original link and `Adam` in tensorflow tutorial, while you have used `RMSprop`. Why is that? Apart from these questions, I am ready to accept your answer. Thanks.

Comment: 1) Relation to your first question
There isn't exactly a specific rule to use. Most people generally use the binary format, 128, 256, 512, etc... You can start off with 784 - 100 - 10. I am using one now that goes from 100 - 50 - 25 - 10. So far, I haven't come across any information on 'optimal' number of neurons to use. But it is better to not use too many like 4096 because you have 4096x10 connections which gives you too many weights and it affects your runtime/memory. MNIST is still small, but when you do larger datasets, it becomes an issue.

Comment: 2) Keras is x.reshape, tensorflow is flatten(), but they both serve the same function

Comment: 3) Your third question is on optimizers. You can read [Keras Documentation](https://keras.io/optimizers/) for more information on the specific details. [This](https://towardsdatascience.com/types-of-optimization-algorithms-used-in-neural-networks-and-ways-to-optimize-gradient-95ae5d39529f) will tell you why you need optimizers

Comment: Great comments. Last question: There are no `dropouts` on this model: http://idiap.ch/~katharas/importance-sampling/ . How important are dropouts?

Comment: Dropouts tend to be more effective on Convolutional Neural Networks (CNN) as verses to Multi-Layer Perceptron Networks (MLP), I personally am unsure about the importance (I have to read up on that!), but it has been known that by 'switching off' some neurons during, the accuracy increases. Someone once gave me the analogy that it is like the brain, and when some neurons are switched off, the firing neurons become more effective at learning the new situation that a human encounters. [This](http://www.cs.toronto.edu/~rsalakhu/papers/srivastava14a.pdf) explains more.